# Uninstalling Entity Framework 4.1 June CTP

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

How can I uninstall EF 4.1 June CTP? I don't see that in Windows 7's Programs and Features list.

pom

Answer (score 0):

It must be in features list - if it is not you found a bug and you should report it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/threads).

I think you meant June 2011 CTP - that is EF 4.2. Follow instructions on [this site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx). Be aware that if you also installed new designer tools CTP you will lose all ADO.NET tools for VS after uninstalling them and you will have to reinstall old version again (also described on mentioned site).